# Multiple IF, ELSEIF statement with && operator using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I want to create a condition to change row colour. But my script didn't working for me. 
Below is my script:

```
if ($getType == 1){
   if (($intervalDay > '1') && ($intervalDay < '7')) {
      $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#43e537">';
      print_r('warna hijau');
   } elseif (($intervalDay > '7') && ($intervalDay < '14')) {
     $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e5e234">';
     print_r('warna kuning');
   } elseif ($intervalDay > 14) {
     $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e54242">';
   } 
} else {
  $strTblRes .= $tmplTbl['row_start']; 
}
```

please can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: remove quotes around number.

Comment: i have try to remove quotes arround number, but still not working.

Comment: Please check which condition is getting executed by adding var_dump.

Comment: maybe declare the variable `$strTblRes` before using it?

Comment: You are going wrong by not explaining what "going wrong" is. What did you try and what results did you get. Did you try all numbers from 0, 1 , 7, 14 and some other like 20 and what happened when you did.

Answer (score 0):

Please update code , i had just put default values

```
$getType=1;

$intervalDay=8;

$strTblRes='';

if ($getType == 1){
   if (($intervalDay > '1') && ($intervalDay < '7')) {
      $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#43e537">';
      print_r('warna hijau');
   } elseif (($intervalDay > '7') && ($intervalDay < '14')) {
     $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e5e234">';
     print_r('warna kuning');
   } elseif ($intervalDay > 14) {
     $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e54242">';
   } 
} else {
  $strTblRes .= "<tr>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 $getType=1;

    $intervalDay=8;

    $strTblRes='';

    if ($getType == 1){
       if ($intervalDay > '1' && $intervalDay < '7') {
          $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#43e537">';
          print_r('warna hijau');
       } elseif ($intervalDay > '7' && $intervalDay < '14'){
         $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e5e234">';
         print_r('warna kuning');
       } elseif ($intervalDay > 14) {
         $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e54242">';
       } 
    } else {
      $strTblRes .= "<tr>"; 
    }
```

Comment: Looks the same as Mayank Majithya who posted first

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($getType == 1){

   if ( $intervalDay > 1  &&  $intervalDay < 7 ) {
      $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#43e537">';
      print_r('warna hijau');
   } 
   if ( $intervalDay > 7  && $intervalDay < 14 ) {
     $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e5e234">';
     print_r('warna kuning');
   } 
   if ($intervalDay > 14) {
     $strTblRes .= '<tr style="background-color:#e54242">';
   } 


} 
else {
  $strTblRes .= $tmplTbl['row_start']; 
}
```